# AngularJS abstracting directives

Tags: angularjs

How does one abstract a directive properly?
As a really basic example, let's say I have this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/h5HXEe?p=info

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.save = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  }

  this.registerListeners = function() {
    console.log('do stuff to register listeners');
  }

  this.otherFunctionsNotToBeChangedWithDifferentInstances() {
    console.log('these should not change between different directives')
  }

  return $scope.testCtrl = this;
});

app.directive("tester", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'testCtrl',
    template: '<button ng-click="testCtrl.save()">save</button>'

  };
});
```

The `tester` directive has some methods on it, but only two will be changed or used depending on where the directive is placed. I could pass in the function as a directive attribute, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. I have been looking at providers, but I am unsure how or if those would even fit into this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting your directive assume that `testCtrl.save()` exist on the scope, you would pass in that function as an attribute. Something like this: http://jsbin.com/jidizoxi/1/edit

Your directive binds the value of the `my-on-click` attribute as a callable function. Your template passes in the controllers `ctrlOnClick()` function, and when the `button`s `ng-click` calls `myOnClick()` Angular will call `ctrlOnClick()` since they are bound to each other.

**EDIT:**

Another common approach is to pass in a config object to the directive. So your controller would look something like:

```
$scope.directiveConfig = {
  method1: function() { ... },
  method2: function() { ... },
  method3: function() { ... },
 ...
}
```

And your template:

```
<my-directive config="directiveConfig"></my-directive>
```

The directive then gets a reference to that object by:

```
scope: {
  config: '='
}
```

The directive can then call methods on the object like this: `$scope.config.method1()`.

Comment: This works fine for small things but I would like a better level of abstraction. What if there are twenty methods I would want to override? Twenty directive attributes would look pretty bad. What about the functions that I do not want to override? In your example if I had two controller sharing functionality I would need to duplicate code between them.